# Fluent NHibernate questions ... Stack Overflow or Google Groups?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, asking-questions, scope, specific-site

It seems like questions are being answered both on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fluent-nhibernate) and [Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/group/fluent-nhibernate).  Which should we use?

It would be nice to have one definitive source to go to for all my Fluent needs. Feel free to chime in, Fluent NHibernate developers.

Comment: Please do not waste time editing and bumping posts from over a decade ago, especially for irrelevant typos and where the last meaningful interaction was more than six years ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask wherever you're most comfortable. We frequent Stack Overflow and the mailing list. I have an RSS feed of any questions tagged fluent-nhibernate, and I check the Google Group nigh-on-constantly.

The way I'd prefer people to do it is:

- Use Stack Overflow for usage questions, which is ideal thanks to its large user base of Fluent and regular NHibernate users. This means I don't have to personally answer every question, and you don't have to rely on me only.
- Use the mailing list for reporting bugs, giving feature suggestions, or listening in on design discussions. This is where your feedback will be listened to.

Comment: This is kinda what I thought.  Thanks for clearing it up.

Answer (score 1):

Stack Exchange has no affiliation with Google Groups whatsoever. Thus, as far as SE is concerned, Stack Overflow is the right place for questions about Fluent Nhibernate.

The question then follows, is a non-SE site better than the respective SE site? Possibly, but in this case, it looks like there's significantly more activity on Stack Overflow, which gets 6–8 posts per day, as opposed to Google Groups, which gets 2–3 posts per day.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I was hoping one of the Fluent devs would comment to see which site they frequented more.  It looks like it might be Google Groups.  I'd up vote you but I don't have enough credit.

Comment: We frequent both.